# pointer type mismatch in conditional expression

Tags: c, pointers

I'm studying pointers, and I copied a quicksort implementation.
 When I compile, gcc shows the error:

> pointer type mismatch in conditional expression

The line that invoked the error is:

```
qSort((void**)lineptr, 0, nlines-1, (int(*)(void*, void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
```

The types in that code are the same as the initialized types:

```
void qSort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
```

Here is the `numcmp` implementation:

```
int numcmp(char *s1, char *s2) 
{ 
    double v1, v2; v1 = atof(s1); 
    v2 = atof(s2); 
    if (v1 < v2) 
        return -1; 
    else if (v1 > v2) 
        return 1; 
    else
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post `numcmp`?, and anyway that's no a good idea in my opinion, write a different `qsort()` for each data type.

Comment: You shouldn't cast a function pointer to a different type. Using it afterwards is undefined.

Comment: And you need two functions with the same prototype in the conditional expression.

Comment: And specially using the ternary operator with variables of different types is not going to compile.

Comment: @sby - Or, you could edit your post with this definition and format it to be readable. :)

Comment: @iharob added numcmp fuction and my teacher wroted as i wrote.

Comment: Does it help if you change the signature of `numcmp` to `int numcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)`?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using the K&R C book? It contains exactly that code. The language has changed since 1988, and if you have a C99 compiler there's a lot in there it will refuse to compile.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck changing signature doesn't help..

Comment: @molbdnilo hmm.. Is The C programming Language second edition wrote by  Dennis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan you said?

Comment: @sby Changing the signature removes the compiler error for me. Perhaps there is a declaration of `numcmp` higher up in the code that you forgot to change.

Answer (score 3):

The conditional expression in question is this:

```
numeric ? numcmp : strcmp
```

The compiler is complaining that the type of the sub-expression `numcmp` is different from the type of the sub-expression `strcmp`.  The former has type `int (*)(char *, char *)`, and the latter has type `int (*)(const char *, const char *)` (provided that you have remembered to `#include <string.h>`, which you must do).  These are not the same, nor even compatible (in the standard's sense of the term "compatible").

You could probably get get around the error by adding `const` qualifiers to the parameters of function `numcmp()`.  GCC may still complain about the cast you perform on the expression's value, however.