# Are char * and const char * compatible when using ternary operator in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, conditional-operator

I got an error from following code. I compiled with gcc6.3.0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINES 5000
char *lineptr[MAXLINES];

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);

void myqsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, 
           int (*comp)(void *, void *));

int numcmp(char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nlines;
    int numeric = 0;

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0)
        numeric = 1;
    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) {
        myqsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,
            (int (*)(void*, void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
        writelines(lineptr, nlines);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("input too big to sort\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
    (int (*)(void*, void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
                                             ^
```

Here are prototypes of the two functions `numcmp` and `strcmp`.

```
int numcmp(char *, char *);
int strcmp(const char *, const char *);
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620885/pointer-type-mismatch-in-conditional-expression), an answerer said they aren't compatible. But n1256 6.5.15 p3 says that(with my bold)

> One of the following shall hold for the second and third operands:
> — both operands have arithmetic type;
> — both operands have the same structure or union type;
> — both operands have void type;
> **— both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;**
> — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant; or
> — one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a
> qualified or unqualified version of void.

They aren't compatible but meet the standard's constraint. But why does the compiler give an error message? Should I convert `int numcmp(char *, char *);` to `int numcmp(const char *, const char *);` in order to use ternary operator?

Comment: I don't know the rules for this particular case and am not near a convenient compiler, but it's worth making numcmp take const char pointers *anyway* to make it a) more useful and b) better convey its intent to not modify the strings pointed to by its arguments. It may very well work, why don't you try it?

Comment: @nanofarad I was solving an exercise from my C book and the function is written in that form. I agree with your idea but I was just curious why my gcc complained with that message.

Comment: Your logic would apply if the two operands were of type `char *` and `const char *`.  But instead they're of types `int (*)(char *, char *)` and `int (*)(const char *, const char *)` which are unqualified pointers to two different types.

Comment: And you can read through the definitions in the standard to convince yourself that "function returning `int` and taking two `char *` parameters" and "function returning `int` and taking two `const char *` parameters" are not compatible types.  It comes down to the fact that `const char` and `char` are not compatible types, because they are not identically qualified: 6.7.3 (9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They aren't compatible but meet the standard's constraint.

I don't think they do.

`numcmp` is of type `int (*)(char *, char *)`, whereas `strcmp` is `int (*)(const char *, const char *)`.   So one is a pointer to `int (char *, char *)` and the other is a pointer to `int (const char *, const char *)`.  Neither of the types `int (char *, char *)` and `int (const char *, const char *)` is qualified; indeed, it is not possible for a function type to be qualified (6.7.3 (8)).  That would be something like `const function returning int` and there's no way for a function to be `const`.

So we're left to ask whether `int (char *, char *)` and `int (const char *, const char *)` are compatible types. They are both function types so we check 6.7.5.3 (15):

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types.

Okay, `int` and `int` are compatible because they are the same type (6.2.7 (1)).

> Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible types.

All right, so we have to find out whether `char *` and `const char *` are compatible types.  They are pointer types so we check 6.7.5.1 (2).

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall
> be pointers to compatible types.

Neither of these types is qualified.  (`char * const` would be `const`-qualified, but `const char *` isn't.)  One is pointer to `char` and the other is pointer to `const char`. So we have to find out whether `char` and `const char` are compatible types. The latter is qualified so we check 6.7.3 (9):

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version
> of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers
> does not affect the specified type.

Oops.  `char` and `char` are compatible types, but `char` and `const char` are not identically qualified, so they're not compatible.