# K&R section 5.11 qsort program generates a warning of pointer-mismatch. Can you explain why this warning is generated?

Tags: c, function-pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

Following is the excerpt from the program: I have tried to re-produce as little code as possible to focus on the warning message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* function declarations */
void userwritelines(char *[],int );
int usernumcmp(char *, char *);

/* constants */
#define MAXLINES 10
#define MAXWIDTHPERLINE 10

void userqsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
char *lineptr[MAXLINES] = { "testing", "whether", "it would", "work"};

int main()
{
    int nlines, numeric;
    nlines = 4;
    numeric = 0;
        userqsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines -1, (int (*)(void *, void *)) (numeric ? usernumcmp : strcmp));
        userwritelines(lineptr, nlines);
        return 0;
}

/* qsort: sort v[left]...v[right] into increasing order */
void userqsort(void *v[], int left, int right,
                int (*comp)(void *, void *))
{
    int i, last;
    void swap(void *v[], int, int);

    if(left >= right)   /* do nothing if array contains */
        return;         /* fewer than 2 elements */

    swap(v, left, (left+right)/2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++)
        if((*comp)(v[i],v[left]) < 0)
            swap(v, ++last, i);

    swap(v, left, last);
    userqsort(v, left, last-1, comp);
    userqsort(v, last+1, right, comp);
}

void swap(void *v[],int i, int j)
{
    void *temp;
    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}

/* writeline function to write the strings as pointed by lineptr i.e. pointer of arrays to char */
void userwritelines(char *lineptr[],int countofline)
{
    while(countofline > 0){
        printf("%s\n",*lineptr);
        lineptr++;
        countofline--;
    }
}

/* usernumcmp: compare s1 and s2 numerically */
int usernumcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    double v1, v2;

    v1 = atof(s1);
    v2 = atof(s2);
    if (v1 < v2)
        return -1;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

when compiled, it generates the following warning:

```
51009396@NHQ-GF-51009396 /cygdrive/d/Let us C/Practice
$ gcc -g -Wall sopointertofunc.c -o sopointertofunc.exe
sopointertofunc.c: In function ‘main’:
sopointertofunc.c:21:100: warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
   15 |         userqsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines -1, (int (*)(void *, void *)) (numeric ? usernumcmp : strcmp));
                                                                                                           ^
```

Can you explain why this warning is getting generated in the first place? While i know the moment i would add `const` keyword to function prototype and definition of usernumcmp function, the warning disappears, but why does the warning appears in the first place?

Comment: What is `usernumcmp`? It is not shown in that code. We need to see a complete [mre].

Comment: What is `"sosection5-11.h"`? Please post a [mcve]. Strip all code non necessary to reproduce this problem, this may mean some work for you.

Comment: Also as a rule of thumb: if you find yourself in need of a cast anywhere in this program, that's a very likely indication of a bug. My guts tell me you are using incorrect function pointer casts, but we need a complete example to tell for sure.

Comment: But for starters suggest you do basic research. Enter the exact warning message into your favourite search engine. I think you'll find the top few results may answer your question or at least inform you what to look for. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620885/pointer-type-mismatch-in-conditional-expression

Comment: The second and third operands of the `?` operator must have the same type. Of course, it's simplified and conversions may be applied in some cases, but this is the rule #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that while computing the following expression:

```
numeric ? usernumcmp : strcmp
```

`usernumcmp` and `strcmp` have different pointer type. You have not shown `usernumcmp` but I would assume `int usernumcmp(int *, int*)` or something close, while `strcmp` is `int strcmp(const char*, const char*)`.

It does not matter much, because you immediately cast the result to `int (*)(void *, void *)` but if you want to get rid of the warning, you should cast the functions **before** computing the expression.

```
typedef int (*compfunc)(void*, void*);
...
userqsort((void**)lineptr, left, right, (numeric ? (cmpfunc) usernumcmp : (cmpfunc)strcmp));
```

Comment: The calls to `usernumcmp` or `strcmp` from `userqsort` are UB (C18 6.5.2.2/9: "**If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined.**"). Hiding warnings with a cast does not fix the UB.

Comment: @IanAbbott would this work  if i redefine and redeclare qsort and usernumcmp as  revised function declarations:      `int usernumcmp (const char *, const char *);`      `void userqsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(char void *, char void *));`  revised function call:      `userqsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines -1, (numeric ? usernumcmp : strcmp));` and would also modify the function definition for userqsort and usernumcmp by adding `const` keyword to their parameter list, just like i did in the function declaration shown in this comment for userqsort and usernumcmp?

Comment: @Singh Just change all the `void`s to `char`s throughout, including the `swap` function and add `const` where required for compatibility: `int usernumcmp(const char *, const char *);` `void userqsort(char *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(const char *, const char *));` `void swap(char *v[], int i, int j);`. Revised function call `userqsort(lineptr, 0, nlines - 1, (numeric ? usernumcmp : strcmp));`.